# SQL query on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Suppose i have the following 2 tables:

```
Persons Table:  
Name  
ID[Primary Key]

Fruits Table:  
Name  
ID[Foreign Key Persons.ID]
```

This is a table structure for storing persons and the fruits they like. Now if I want to find all the persons who like "Apple" **and** "Orange"(this would be dynamic). How can i design a SQL query for that?

Comment: This is a bad design for your problem. You have to design a `many-to-many` relationship

Comment: @wajeeh can give details?

Comment: You need `Person` and `Fruit` tables, each one having its `primary key`. Then you need `Person_Fruits` table as a join between the previous two tables. This table must have to `Foreign keys` for each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like the following to get the IDs of all persons who like Apples **and** Oranges:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM Persons AS p
JOIN Fruits AS f ON p.ID = f.PersonsID
WHERE f.Name IN ('Apple', 'Orange')
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT f.Name) = 2
```